# Fixed Div the length of the window

Tags: html, css

I am very new to HTML/CSS. I am building a website for the Sheriff's office I work for, and am having an issue.

The website has a fixed div on the left side of the page, that includes all of the links. The content is on the right, and is designed to scroll, however I want the left div (links) to always remain the same. I designed the site on a laptop, and so far its working fine on that, however when viewing the homepage on a desktop, the left div doesnt stretch all the way to the bottom.

Here is the link: `http://www.mlpropmgt.com/sheriff3/index.html`

I used percentages, thinking that would make that left div always stretch to the bottom of the screen, however it didnt seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: we will need your code HTML/CSS to answer

Comment: Mind if you put your code which states the problem here and send us the link of your work? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sheriff's office? Great. :) Btw, there are more problems - test site on different screen resolutions, and you will see... Menu position is wrong, too, on higher resolutions.

Comment: do you have any ideas on how to fix the menu problem you mention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have 2 divs do this

```
<div id="Main_div">
    <div id="left_div">div 1</div>
    <div id="Right_div">div 2</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#Main_div
  {
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
   }

     #left_div
      {
        border:1px solid black;
        height:100%;
        width:40%;
        float:left;
        position:fixed;
       }

       #Right_div
      {
        border:1px solid blue;
        height:100%;
        marigh-left:41%;
        float:right; // or its not needed

       }
```

let us know

Answer (score 1):

from what I gather viewing the code in your webpage you did all the right things, and the leftbar is 100% height, however the image you used as a background is not, css does not stretch the image unless you tell it to do it, you can use

```
.leftbar{ background-size: cover;}
```

or use an image that is big enough to account for the extra height in a desktop, keep in mind that Imac's hace 1440px window height

Answer (score 0):

give height of the div as 100% (`height:100%;`) then set `position:fixed;`
it will works fine

Answer (score 0):

Hi righ now your left side it has 100% height so is working the div is streching all the way to the bottom. The problem is the background image. The background image is smaller than a desktop window height so that's why it looks like is not streching all the way to the bottom.

Possible solutions:

1. Change the background image to a bigger one that just have the "background", and put another two images with the sherif star and the sheriff's logo/name with a absolute position so they will look like background images.
2. You can add the following to your leftbar div. The problem here is that the image is going to strech and at some point you are not going to be able to see the complete logo/name

   ```
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   ```